# Minimal 3NF normalization issues

Tags: database-design, normalization, database-theory

I'm trying to learn how to normalize to *3NF* but the example that my teacher gave us doesn't really help.

The algorithm I always used is this one:

1. Find a canonical cover F_c for F
2. For each FD X->Y in F_c create a relation with schema XY
3. Eliminate a relation if its schema is a subset of another
4. Merge those remaining relations into a relation which has all the keys for the db

I also tried the algorithm found in [this other question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73155/3nf-decomposition-im-not-sure-about-this-example) but I'm still failing for this particular example.

So, here's the example (starting from the canonical cover):

```
R<A,B,C,D,E,F,H>
C->DF; A->H; HF->C; B->E; AD->B; E->D; AB->F
Keys = {AC, AF, AD, AB, AE}
```

Since we already have the canonical cover, let's follow the second step:

```
<R1(C,D,F), {C->DF}>
<R2(A,H), {A->H}>
<R3(C,F,H), {HF->C; C->F}>
<R4(B,E), {B->E}>
<R5(A,B,D), {AD->B; B->D; A->D}>
<R6(D,E), {E->D}>
<R7(A,B,F), {AB->F; F->B}>
```

Before going on, here's the first question: he takes *some* of the projections from the schema, but there's one that really doesn't make any sense to me. I'm talking about `A->D` from `R5`.

The paths leading to `D` are the ones with `E` or `C`, so let's see if we can use them:

- `C` is reached by `HF`, where `H` is reached by `A` and `F` by `AB`, meaning that `A` can't get to `C` without `B`
- `E` is reached by `B`, where `B` is reached by `AD`, meaning again that `A` can't get to `E` without `D`

So the first question is: *why does he take that `A->D` projection if isn't there a way for `A` alone to reach `D`? Am I missing something?*

*Please note that the same question applies to `F->B` in `R7`, because I don't think that `F` can reach `B` without `A`, that's why I think it should be `AF->B`*

Coming back to the example, let's go on with the algorithm. As we can see there are no relations sharing attributes, so there's nothing to merge/eliminate at step 3.

It's now time for step 4, but his result is the following (he didn't write the FDs here):

```
R1'(A,B,D,E) - merged R4, R5, R6
R2'(A,B,C,F,H) - merged R2, R3, R7
R3'(C,D,F) - R1 was not merged and didn't change
```

The problem here is that we're presented with this final result without any explanation on how we got here. He just merged those relations and I really don't understand why.

Can you please try to explain how this works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A. Canonical Cover**

The example is *almost* a canonical cover, since in a canonical cover each dependency has only an attribute on the right part, so the dependency

```
C → DF
```

must be replaced by the two dependencies:

```
C → D
C → F
```

**B. Second step of the 3NF Synthesis Algorithm**

The step says to divide the functional dependencies in groups with the same left part, and create a relation scheme with all the attributes of each group, not to create a relation for each functional dependency. In this case the effect is the same as your solution.

So the second step produces the following schemas:

```
R1 <(A H), { A → H }>    
R2 <(A B D), { A D → B }>    
R3 <(A B F), { A B → F }>    
R4 <(B E), { B → E }>    
R5 <(C D F), { C → D, C → F }>    
R6 <(D E), { E → D }>    
R7 <(C F H), { F H → C }>
```

Note that in this the decomposition the dependencies shown are only the original dependencies used to produce the decomposition, since in the algorithm the projection of the dependencies is *not* calculated, and this is due to the fact that this computation requires an exponential algorithm.

If, however, we look at the projection of the dependencies, *here you are correct*, since both A → D and F → B are not present in the projection. Here is the above decomposition together with a projection of the original dependencies over the subschema:

```
R1 <(A H), { A → H }>    
R2 <(A B D), { A D → B, B → D }>    
R3 <(A B F), { A B → F, A F → B }>    
R4 <(B E), { B → E }>    
R5 <(C D F), { C → D, C → F }>    
R6 <(D E), { E → D }>    
R7 <(C F H), { F H → C, C → F }>
```

**C. Third step of the 3NF Synthesis Algorithm**

Correct

**D. Fourth step of the 3NF Synthesis Algorithm**

Here again the step is incorrect. The fourth step simply says: “if no schema exists with a key of the original relation, than add a new schema with this key”. See for instance Algorithm 16.6, R.Elmasri, S.B. Navathe, Foundamentals of Database Systems, 6th Edition, pag. 561 (or any other good book on databases):

> If none of the relation schemas in D contains a key of R, then create one more relation schema in D that contains attributes that form a key of R.

And since in this case *there* exist relations with a key, no other relation must be added, and the final decomposition is not modified:

```
R1 <(A H)>    
R2 <(A B D)>    
R3 <(A B F)>    
R4 <(B E)>    
R5 <(C D F)>    
R6 <(D E)>    
R7 <(C F H)>
```

So the solution given, with R1', R2' and R3' is *not* correct and it is not in Third Normal Form. It is easy to show this. Taking for instance the second relation,

```
R2' (A B C F H)
```

and projecting the original dependencies over it, we found the following dependencies:

```
{ A F → B
  A B → C
  A → H
  C → F
  F H → C }
```

with keys:

```
{ (A B) (A C) (A F) }
```

So we can see that the dependency `A → H` violates the Third Normal Form (`A` is not a (super)key and `H` is not a prime attribute).

---

As shown in the answer, if the relations must still be in 3NF, the final solution with three schemas is not the minimal 3NF normalization, since the relation R2' **is not in 3NF**. In other words, the solution is incorrect.

The classical synthesis algorithm produces the decomposition in 7 relations. I am not aware of any published algorithm that will *minimize* the number of relations obtained by that algorithm. You could try to combine relations and check if the combination is still in 3NF, but note that *checking if a relation is in 3NF is an exponential task*, since one should find all the keys, to exclude the possibility that a determinate be a prime attribute.